# Open URL in a browser and catch response

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, console-application

I am working on a console application project which will integrate an Oauth 2.0 flow. Oauth 2.0 flow will require the user to input their username and password to grant the application.

Let's say i have this code to open the authorization page in a browser

```
Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "http://example.com/auth_page/";
        proc.Start();
```

The flow of the program is,

1. the user will click the login button from my application,
2. Oauth 2.0 authorization page will pop up thru browser
3. Input username and password to grant authorization
4. The authorization page will give us access token thru redirect uri.

Other approach:

1. Request an OAuth 2.0 authorisation code with the required scope 
   then the user will be redirected to the login screen. When they've submitted their credentials, they'll be asked to authorise your application to access the requested scope. - basically this will open a new browser tab
2. After successfully signing in my program the program will Exchange the OAuth 2.0 authorisation code for an access token - this can be done via HttpWebrequest or RestClient

The problem is, how to catch the response of the browser response or response url? Is this achievable in Process? Thanks

Comment: Why not do what Azure does? Azure generates a token (for example, azure.com/a_token) that redirects to login, then uses the credentials and token to verify the login.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am considering that, but the project requirements is we need to do it in just a console app or no third parties related.

Comment: Do you mean is that I will redirect to example.com/auth_page/? I think that what I'm trying to achieve via console app.

Comment: Yes, you're right. 
1. Request an OAuth 2.0 authorisation code with the required scope -  The user will be redirected to the login screen. When they've submitted their credentials, they'll be asked to authorise your application to access the requested scope.
2. Exchange the OAuth 2.0 authorisation code for an access token.

I'm trying to achieve Step 1 so that I can exchange the OAuth 2.0 code for an access token